# configuring button on touch pro's stylus to open onenote 2016

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-surface-pro, microsoft-onenote-2016

So I have two versions of OneNote on my Microsoft Surface Pro 4. OneNote 2016 (Desktop app) and OneNote (Trusted Windows Store app). The former was installed when I installed Office 2016 and the latter was pre-installed.

Problem is...  when I hit the eraser button on the stylus that came with the Surface Pro the preinstalled version of OneNote comes up. I'd rather the paid-for version come up instead.

Any idea how I can change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

Per https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/touch-mouse-and-search/surface-pen-default-onenote?os=windows-10 you need to do the following:

1. Open the Surface app.
2. On the left side of the app, select the Pen icon.
3. Under Button Customization, choose which action to take when you single-click, double-click, or press and hold the top button on your pen.

I changed "Single-click" to "Launch a desktop app" and from there selected `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ONENOTE.EXE`.